# How to use Group_Concat() to concat in MySql

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I have table structure like this-

```
 Code         Codelang          Name

  14           de              David
  14           en              Michel
  14           es              John
```

I want to show this table as-

```
 Code                Name

 14               [:de]David[:en]Michel[:es]John[:]
```

Is it possible to do this using Group_Concat() or is there any other way to do this.?

Comment: This is, at best, a very strange task to ask of the database.  Perhaps it's a manipulation that you should perform in the presentation layer of your application (i.e. in the program code that accesses MySQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  code,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[:',codelang,']',name) SEPARATOR '') as name
FROM table1
GROUP BY code
```

to get  **[:]** at the end you can try:

```
SELECT
  code,
  CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[:',codelang,']',name) SEPARATOR ''),'[:]') as name
FROM table1
GROUP BY code
```

Comment: hello thanks Alex for reply. using your code I am getting this-
`[:de]David[:en]Michel[:es]John`  it  is missing `[:]` at the end.

Comment: What will be the mysql query if I want to copy this column data to another column.? I have got follwing structure after applying above query.

`Code`   `Nombre`
 `14`      `[:de]David[:en]Michel[:es]John[:]`

Comment: I don't understand... why do you need data to be copied using sql?

Comment: Hey Alex Please check- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862294/what-will-be-right-mtsql-syntax-to-copy-a-column-data-to-another-column