# What will be right mysql syntax to copy a column data to another column

Tags: mysql

I have table(mytable1) like-

```
Code     Nombre
14       [:de]David[:en]Michel[:es]John[:]
...       .......
...      ........
```

I have another table(mytable2) like-

```
Code    Post_title
```

I want to copy data of column Nombre of mytable1 to Post_title column of mytable2.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable2 
LEFT JOIN mytable1
ON mytable1.code=mytable2.code
SET mytable2.post_title = mytable1.nombre
```